# Получить всех пользователей jira конкретной группы

Tags: api, rest, jira

Как получить всех пользователей конкретной группы проекта (developers) используя jira rest api?

Comment: получить всех пользователей конкретной группы, или проекта, или и группы и проекта?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor конкретного проекта, в нем конкретной группы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Официальная [документация](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-groups/)

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/group?groupname=developers&expand=users' \
  --user 'email@example.com:<api_token>' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

`expand=users` тут необходим, иначе не покажет их

требуется роль админа или же уровень доступа `read:jira-user`

еще есть [отдельная ручка](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-groups/#api-rest-api-3-group-member-get) для получения юзеров в конкретной группе

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/group/member?groupname=developers&includeInactiveUsers=false&maxResults=1000' \
  --user 'email@example.com:<api_token>' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

ответ

```
{
  "self": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/group/member?groupname=jira-administrators&includeInactiveUsers=false&startAt=2&maxResults=2",
  "nextPage": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/group/member?groupname=jira-administrators&includeInactiveUsers=false&startAt=4&maxResults=2",
  "maxResults": 2,
  "startAt": 3,
  "total": 5,
  "isLast": false,
  "values": [
    {
      "self": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/user?accountId=5b10a2844c20165700ede21g",
      "name": "",
      "key": "",
      "accountId": "5b10a2844c20165700ede21g",
      "emailAddress": "mia@example.com",
      "avatarUrls": {},
      "displayName": "Mia",
      "active": true,
      "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney",
      "accountType": "atlassian"
    },
    {
      "self": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/user?accountId=5b10a0effa615349cb016cd8",
      "name": "",
      "key": "",
      "accountId": "5b10a0effa615349cb016cd8",
      "emailAddress": "will@example.com",
      "avatarUrls": {},
      "displayName": "Will",
      "active": false,
      "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney",
      "accountType": "atlassian"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для меня работает вот это:

```
GET /rest/api/latest/user/search?query=+&maxResults=1000
```

Comment: а как в query отобразить конкретную группу?